# Assigning range and type to chart in other workbook

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I need to create charts from CSV-files. This happens every day, for quite a few tables, so I automated it.

When the CSV files are created, they're stored in the folder from that day.

When I open my VBA script it'll read all the CSV files in that folder, and paste all the tables (each on a new sheet, obviously) together in a new workbook.

```
With NewBook
  Set sv = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(i))
  sv.Name = SvName

    < Add CSV-files to just created sheet >

  With sv
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print SvName & ":" & vbTab & "Cells(" & LastRow; ", " & LastColumn & ")"
  End With

  Set svChart = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(SvName))
  svChart.Name = SvName & " Chart"
  With svChart
    .Shapes.AddChart.Name = SvName & "-cht"

     With .Shapes(SvName & "-cht")
      .Left = Range("A1").Left
      .Top = Range("A1").Top
      .Width = Range("A1:AC56").Width
      .Height = Range("A1:AC56").Height
    End With

  End With
End With
```

The code above works fine, but is only drawing the parent of the chart. all options i found which supposed to make it a line chart, for example

```
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
```

and for the range

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```

result in an error like

> "With not set"

or

> "This option is not available for this object"

Comment: just a quick check: did you select the chart? (Shapes().Select) otherwise ActiiveChart wouldn't work...

Comment: @therak, yes I've tried that. with .Select and .Activate. both result in the same errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the chart that you create with `AddChart` :

With your code :

```
Dim oChart As Chart
Set oChart = .Shapes.AddChart
    oChart.Name = SvName & "-cht"
    oChart.ChartType = xlLine
    oChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```

With my code (without `Shapes`) :

```
Dim oChart As Chart
Set oChart = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
    oChart.Name = SvName & "-cht"
    oChart.ChartType = xlLine
    oChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```

---

##
Here is your full code with the implemantation that I proposed :

```
Dim oChart As Chart

With NewBook
  Set sv = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(i))
  sv.Name = SvName

    '< Add CSV-files to just created sheet >

  With sv
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print SvName & ":" & vbTab & "Cells(" & LastRow; ", " & LastColumn & ")"
  End With

  Set svChart = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(SvName))
  svChart.Name = SvName & " Chart"
  With svChart

    Set oChart = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
    'oChart.Select
    oChart.Name = SvName & "-cht"
    oChart.ChartType = xlLine
    oChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

     With .Shapes(SvName & "-cht")
      .Left = Range("A1").Left
      .Top = Range("A1").Top
      .Width = Range("A1:AC56").Width
      .Height = Range("A1:AC56").Height
    End With

  End With
End With
```

Here is what I use when I want to create a Chart in Excel :

```
Sub Graph()

Dim Gr As Chart, _
    Sr As Series, _
    Src_Name As String

Src_Name = "Sheet1"
Set Gr = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add

With Gr
    '----Source Data Definition
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(1197, 2)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    '----Graph Type
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    '----Location/Placement
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="NewSheetName"
    '----Title
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Chart Title"


    '----Data Series 1
    Set Sr = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With Sr
        .Values = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 2), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5))
        .XValues = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 1))
        .AxisGroup = 1
        .Name = "MTTF"
    End With
    '----Data Series 2
    Set Sr = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With Sr
        .Values = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 2), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5))
        .XValues = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 1))
        .Name = "MTTR"
        '----Placing a Serie on Second axis
        .AxisGroup = 2
    End With
    '----Series' formats
    '.SeriesCollection(i).Delete
    '----For a line type chart
    '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Weight = 1
    '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(int1 as integer, int1 as integer, int3 as integer)
    '----For an area type chart
    '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(int1 as integer, int1 as integer, int3 as integer)

    '----Axis parameters
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Age"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Hours"
    .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDot
    .ChartArea.Font.Size = 14
    .Deselect

    '----Legend positioning
    With .Legend
        .Left = 350
        .Top = 75
    End With
    '----Drawing area positiong
    With .PlotArea
        .Width = 550
        .Height = 350
    End With
End With

'----Free memory
Set Gr = Nothing
Set Sr = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the quick responds. I tried it, and still gives me the same errors:
   Error 438 during execution.
   This methode is not available for the object.
on both the lines with ChartType and SetSourceData

Comment: Hmmm... This is strange, even the macro recorder + Object browser agrees... I added a `Select` to active the Chart, not sure it'll be enough but there is nothing else more in macro recording...

Comment: @Roffel : I added my base when I work with Charts and proposed something else for referencing the Chart, let me know if it works! ;)